# How to programatically offset UItableviewcontroller with navbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

How can I programatically add a navbar to a UITableViewController and offset the actual table view to where it starts right where the navbar ends.  This is what i've done so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationBar *myBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    [self.view addSubview:myBar];

    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 0, 0)];

}
```

but this is the result:

[image]

The reason I cannot just simply imbed a navigation controller is because im using this UITableViewController as a UIView for a childviewcontroller.  Im doing this to get a paged UIScrollView much like snapchat.  Whenever I try to just embed the navigation controller into this UITableViewController it doesnt show up during simulation.

For any further details on what Im trying to accomplish You can check out https://github.com/wannabegeek/PageViewController since that is the project im getting this off of.

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate this does not answer your question, however you can do  proper screenshot from the simulator with CMD-S, rather than taking a photo with your device.

Comment: Oh thanks @Nick I'll definitely use that next time

Comment: why not just set the tableviewcontroller as the root view controller of a navigation controller ? You're gonna get the same thing. better too\

Comment: Well thats what i tried to do but as I said it doesn't show up in the simulator.  If you check out that project you'll see why. Im using this UITableViewController in place of the projects "View 3"

Comment: If you hold down the on/off button at top and click the home button, it will take a screenshot that is in your photo library.  You can also take a screenshot from the devices/organizer page in Xcode.